Subfloor warping, bad install?
I had a contractor come out 9 months ago to install vinyl plank laminate flooring throughout my home. He told me all but 2 of the rooms needed the subfloor torn up and replaced with what I believe was 1/4" plywood. There were 2 rooms which he told me the flooring was still good so he put the laminate over the existing wood pop-in tiles.
About a month after it was all done, I noticed the floors were lifting up and it turns out he used nails instead of screws so he had to come back every few weeks to remove the laminate and screw down the subfloor since it was happening gradually room by room. Fast forward a few months later and I'm noticing the rooms with the new subfloor are becoming very wavy and uneven. The laminate has started to come up as well.
As for the 2 rooms that he put the laminate on top of the original wood tile, even worse. There are now big hills in those rooms because apparently the old flooring wasn't good as he had said.
I'm not sure what to do. I feel defeated. I am still under warranty but the guy would give me crap every time he came out and would try to push the problem on us. Could this be a bad install?

https://yourniftyhome.com/how-thick-should-subfloor-be/

I figured that was the case but what do I do? Do I call him back show him that it's unacceptable? If he refuses to fix it do I have a case for small claims court?

1/4 inch or thinner plywood is under layment and goes on top of a sub floor to make it smooth(er).  If used as the sub floor, surprised no one fell though.

Maybe I was confused, it was used as under layment. But still, what should I do?

THis a a question of whether the underlayment is the issue or the flooring itself.  First tell us if you have vinyl plank often called LVP flooring or Laminate flooring which is a hard plastic surface backed by wood fiber composite.   The latter expand and contracts at a greater rate and needs to be acclimated before installation.  LVP does not require acclimation and has a much lower expansion and contraction rate.  Understand what is causing your problems greatly depends on knowing exactly what type of flooring your have.

It is vinyl plank

It is the underlayment for sure because it is very noticeable when I walk on it.

Then you must have the contractor replace the underlayment.

This isn't a DIY question. As for contracts, depends what region you're in but matters like this are prone to get litigious. What does your contract say about such "guarantees"? In my area, if a contractor or salesperson can't "make it right" they have to refund the money. For less money and headache, you might get a GC or inspector involved who a) understands the process better and b) can liaise with the flooring person to ensure it's done right. the If floorer is not bonded and insured, he's likely to dump the job and you're at square 1.

What about the 2 rooms that never had anything replaced? He said the original flooring was still good and he put LVP on top of the existing flooring and now that flooring is all puffed up. Am I screwed there?

LVP can go over most flat hard flooring, except carpet.  Did any of the floors have a bounce to them when walking on them before?

I wonder if what's happening here is that the installer didn't leave sufficient edge gap and now the LVP has expanded.
